# react-google-maps to @react-google-maps/api migration, constant for OverlayType

Tags: react-google-maps

My app uses the DrawingManager to draw a polygon. 
in react-google-maps, the "window.google" variable makes constants available. 
What is proper syntax in "@react-google-map/api" ?

react-google-maps:

```html
<GoogleMap ... >
      <DrawingManager
        defaultDrawingMode={google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON}
        ...
        />
</GoogleMap>
```

now (very similar)

@react-google-maps/api:

```html
<GoogleMap ... >
      <DrawingManager
        drawingMode={google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON}
        ...
        />
</GoogleMap>
```

Tried many syntax... not working. Get the feeling window.google is explicitely deleted at startup. I guess it is normal but how to get constants ?

I get the message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'OverlayType' of undefined
```

Thanks a lot for help !

Answer (score 0):

ok, this one was simple, needed to add 'drawing' to libraries prop

```html
<LoadScript
    googleMapsApiKey="..."
    libraries={["drawing"]}
>
    <TheWholeApp />
</LoadScript>
```

Since that, no issue for

```html
<DrawingManager
    drawingMode={google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON}
    ... 
/>
```

Comment: An other issue I had to make DrawingManager working, was react and react-dom version. It was 16.4 and and kept having an error message saying "setMap: map is not an instance of Map" or something similar. Upgrade to latest react and react-dom (16.8 currently) solved the issue.